# Add string to pandoc resources path

Tags: pandoc

I have some markdown files which reference some images, and I would like to both export these as static html and host them on a website, and also export them locally to PDF via pandoc.

My working directory has my images located in `/assets/images/image.png`.

The html website requires that the image path be reference exactly like `/assets/images/image.png`, such that it will locate the image from the root of the website. However,  pandoc instead requires `assets/images/image.png` OR `./assets/images/image.png`. As it stand, images cannot be located properly BOTH the website and pandoc.

Is there a way to simply append a string of `.` in the pandoc resource path options to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for pandoc's [Lua filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.HTML). Something along the lines of

```lua
-- prepend a slash to all image paths
function Image (img)
  img.src = '/' .. img.src
  return IMG
end
```

Save the filter to a file and pass it to pandoc via the `--lua-filter` command line option.

Check out the [`pandoc.path` module](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#module-pandoc.path) if you need to do more complex operations.